# I have an error on Magento "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'observe' of null "

Tags: magento

So, this is the website I'm having a problem with: www.filteright.com

When I try to place an order I get to the final step ( after I add credit card details ) and I press place order but nothing happens ( it says loading and then it stops. I've checked the console in chrome (F12) and this is the error I'm getting.

If you want to try it for youself you can use these credit card data:
Visa
Card N°: 4900 0000 0000 0003
Date of Expiry: 12/2015
CVV: 123
( it's from sellxed test credit card data )

I guess something is wrong with this line of code

```
$('subscription_plan').observe('change', function(event){
```

I don't have much experience with magento but I'm trying to help someone figure this out.

I would really appreciate if you could tell me what's wrong there.

```
<script>
var subscriptionForm = new VarienForm('subscription-form');
subscriptionForm.submit = function () {
    return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(subscriptionForm)();
}

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $('subscription_plan').observe('change', function(event){
        var index = this.value;
        $$('.plan-details').each(function(element, index){
            element.hide();
        });
        if ($('plan-details-' + index)) {
            $('plan-details-' + index).show();
        }
    });

    $('btn-change-subscription').observe('click', function(event){

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to tell *us* what's wrong. What are you trying to do? What did you expect to get, and what are you getting? You should edit your question and add more information about your problem.

Comment: Hello @Jubobs I've added more infos. I don't know what I can provide more than this.

Comment: That's better. I can't help you, but I'm sure others will.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PrototypeJS related question.
The error you are receiveing is because it can't find the element in DOM, for which `.observe()` is called.

Check in the page source to have in page the elements with the 
`id="subscription_plan"` or `id="btn-change-subscription"`. If you can't find them, then you have to find the reason for which they are not in the page.